# Extract square-bracketed text from a string

Tags: python

Could someone please help me strip characters from a string to leave me with just the characters held within '[....]'?

```
For example:

a  = newyork_74[mylocation]

b = # strip the frist characters until you reach the first bracket [

c = [mylocation]
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Can the `[]`s be nested?

Comment: This sounds like a job for [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no nested structures, one way would be using [`itertools.dropwhile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile),

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> b = ''.join(dropwhile(lambda c: c != '[', a))
>>> b
'[mylocation]'
```

Another would be to use [`regexs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html),

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile(r'\[.*\]')
>>> b = pat.search(a).group(0)
>>> b
'[mylocation]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> strs = "newyork_74[mylocation]"
>>> re.sub(r'(.*)?(\[)','\g<2>',strs)
'[mylocation]'
```